# Can I run a Google Colab (free edition) script and then shut down my computer?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Can I run a google colab (free edition) script and then shut down my computer?

I am training several deeplearning models with crossvalidation, and therefore I would like to know if I can close the window or the computer with the training running at the same time in the cloud.

Comment: Maybe this is something you are looking for https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4442/how-to-shut-down-the-computer-after-a-task-has-been-completed
Do you want to send some message to your PC from google-colab machine?

Comment: Thank you for answering, but this is not what i am looking for.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

### 2024 Update:

At the time of writing the original answer, Google Colaboratory was an entirely free service and there was no official support for [background execution](https://colab.research.google.com/signup?utm_source=faq&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=what_are_usage_limits#:%7E:text=What%20is%20%E2%80%9Cbackground,expand_more) of a notebook as the question describes. While we previously arrived at some estimates for notebook lifetimes through anecdotal experience, these estimates are no longer reliable and you will find that Colaboratory prunes your notebook runtimes much more aggressively now.

The answer to the question now would be simply **no, you may not reliably have a Google Colab notebook running in the background without shelling out for a Colab Pro+ subscription, or using a workaround that infringes on Colab's usage policies.**

If you're in a position where you do not have access to GPUs, nor the funds to pay for access to them but need them for long-running tasks, you may take a look at this non-exhaustive list of alternatives. However, they all come with usage restrictions, or involve a learning curve to use:

- [Saturn Cloud Free Plan](https://saturncloud.io/plans/saturn_cloud_plans/)
  The Saturn Cloud platform provides [150 free compute hours per month](https://saturncloud.io/blog/150-free-hours/)
- [Amazon SageMaker](https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/)
  As part of the [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Types=*all&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Categories=categories%23ai-ml), you get 250 hours of usage of an ML instance for the first two months
- [Colab Pro+](https://colab.research.google.com/signup?utm_source=faq&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=what_are_usage_limits#:%7E:text=an%20integrated%20chatbot.-,Colab%20Pro%2B,-%2449.99%20per%20month)
  If you bite the bullet and sign up for a Colab Pro+ subscription, you may run a notebook in the background for up to 24 hours as long as you have available compute units.

---

### Previous answer circa 2019:

With the browser closed, a Colabs instance will run for at most
<del>12 hours</del> 90 minutes before your runtime is considered idle and is recycled.

At the same time, it would be good practice to save your model weights periodically to avoid losing work.

Comment: Based on my own recent experience, I believe Colab will allocate you at most 12 hours of GPU usage, after which there is roughly an 8 hour cool-down period before you can use compute resources again. In my case, I could not connect to an instance even without a GPU. I'm not entirely sure about this next bit but I think if you run say 3 instances at once, your 12 hours are depleted 3 times as fast. I don't know after what period of time the 12 hour limit resets, but I'd guess maybe a day.

Comment: have you tested keeping it running on a smartphone?

Comment: The last time I tried this was in early 2019, I'm not sure about whether it still works today.

Comment: What is considered 'idle' state? If I was to not click on the colab tab, but have it open in my browser, would this also be considered 'idle' state? And what about the 12 hours max restriction - is it only holding if you use a hosted GPU/TPU or the restriction also in place when you run colab locally?

Comment: What's the point of being always online? it is just stupid. Training a model could take weeks to get completed.

Answer (score 29):

Open your browser console and copy and paste the code bellow, that will avoid you to get kicked off for being idle.

```js
function ClickConnect() {
console.log("Working"); 
document
  .querySelector('#top-toolbar > colab-connect-button')
  .shadowRoot.querySelector('#connect')
  .click() 
}
setInterval(ClickConnect, 60000)
```

Ps. You will get kicked after 12 hours no matter what, so be sure that you are saving your progress to your Google Drive.

Comment: I did that. and now I am annoyed by the dialog always poping up. How can I undo this? or disable this?

Comment: If you got annoyed it means you're looking to it, if you're looking to it what's the point to use it if you can just move your mouse to avoid getting kicked for being idle? 

Comment:  yes. I was refering to using it while being away from my screen for an extended period of time but then returning back to continue working on it.

Comment: Sort-of-related tip: create a VM and then VNC into it for long-running notebooks. That way, you can shut down your current machine or close all windows and not have to worry about losing your work. I've tried all other tricks, and this works the best for me.

Comment: Like @gota I also used this and had no idea how to stop it. I turned the interval down to 3 to check it worked and then the instance crashed. How do you turn it off?

Comment: @AdamMurphy You can probably try to clear out the interval timer.

Comment: @cyperpunk can you be a bit more precise in how I would do that? Do you mean deleting the number in the `setInterval` call?

Comment: @AdamMurphy Please refer https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-cleartimeout-clearinterval-method/

Comment: Can you give some more instructions where in Google Chrome to paste the code snippet? Just paste it in the white space under "settings"->"more tools"->"developer tools"-> "console"? Or should I go under sources and create a new file for that? a screen shot would be great! thx

Answer (score 4):

#### Shell Loop

for me, I choose ,chroot into VM by ssh Ngrok and run command  shell (loop) in background
`while true;do sleep 300; done &`
I'm using&` for to run this command in the background
so I can exit from website of colab and leave the VM working, for 12h

#### ssh Ngrok

The best way to use ssh in colab , you must sign one time in `ngrok.com` and get your OAuth key and add this cell to your colab notebook

```
#@title **SSH**

! pip install colab_ssh --upgrade &> /dev/null

Ngrok = True  

try:
    if username:
        pass
    elif password:
        pass
except NameError:
    !echo "root:root"   | chpasswd
    username='root'
    password='root'




#@markdown [OAuth](https://dashboard.ngrok.com/auth)
ngrokToken = "" #@param {type:'string'}


def runNGROK():
    from colab_ssh import launch_ssh
    from IPython.display import clear_output
    launch_ssh(ngrokToken, password)
    clear_output()

    print("ssh", username, end='@')
    ! curl -s http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels | python3 -c \
            "import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)['tunnels'][0]['public_url'][6:].replace(':', ' -p '))"










if Ngrok:
    if ngrokToken == "":
        print("No ngrokToken Found, Please enter it")
    else:
        runNGROK()
```

now past your OAuth key in Edite text in colab cell , after 3-9 seconde you see your ssh like that

```
ssh root@2.tcp.ngrok.io -p 13225
```

dont forget change password of root user (default is root) ,for more security, you should be change linux password of root user  `!echo "root:new password"   | chpasswd`  and from python  variable by : `password =password='new password'` , you must matching linux password and var python password , look in this ligne above:

```
print("No user found using username and password as 'root'")
    !echo "root:t"   | chpasswd
    username='root'
    password='root'
```

Answer (score 2):

use multiprocess in python make one other function and start while loop there! that while loop won't let it sleep!