# Will my google colab program end after i close the webpage?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am running a deep learning training program on my colab notebook which will cost about 10hours. If i close my browser, will it be shutdown by google before it ends as expected? Or will the last output be saved coorectly in my Drive?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55050988/can-i-run-a-google-colab-free-edition-script-and-then-shutdown-my-computer) and [here](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html). Basically, the code should keep running, but after some time (around 90 minutes) of idle activity, the notebook should be cut off, so I assume that what you suggest is not viable. Maybe you could try to launch the script in the morning and interact with it every 20-30 minutes to prevent it going to idle. Also, consider using [Google Colab pro](https://colab.research.google.com/signup) (faster GPUs and longer runtimes, but never longer that 24 hours)

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to that question is a solid no. Your session will go ahead and continue executing or will stay idle, as stated in the @SilentCloud 's Answer above it will go for about

#### 90 Minutes [With CPU]

#### 30 Minutes [With GPU]

The reason I say 30 Minutes with GPU is that I have personally tested that and it appears to be this number, as do use on a rather regular basis.

You can make a simple bot on Your Machine using `pyautogui` in order to go ahead and do some random stuff if for some reason it makes more economical sense, or you are not interested in **Google Colab Pro** Subscription.

[image: Google Colab Subscription]

## Run with Browser Closed

If you want a seamless experience with the browser window effectively closed and having access to GPU's that are much more better and faster, I would recommend the **Colab Pro +** Subscription.

But the Scripting Idea is there, and your mileage may vary.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. It's really a good idea to click the page automatically using pyautogui!