# How long can I run Google Colab if I don't use GPU

Tags: google-colaboratory

I know there is a limit on how much GPU you can use on Google Colab but what if you are just running a regular CPU script. Is there a limit to how long I can run it for?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55050988/can-i-run-a-google-colab-free-edition-script-and-then-shut-down-my-computer) but it is unclear whether it's talking about with GPU or without GPU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From their [docs](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html)

> Notebooks run by connecting to virtual machines that have maximum
> lifetimes that can be as much as 12 hours. Notebooks will also
> disconnect from VMs when left idle for too long. Maximum VM lifetime
> and idle timeout behavior may vary over time, or based on your usage.

If your notebook is not idle: 12 hours. If it is: 90 minutes after it becomes idle. This applies to using GPU or CPU.