# How to RUN the NAMD codes in google colab for longer periods (12 hours)?

Tags: shell, google-colaboratory

I am trying to run a molecular dynamic simulation on google colab. I'm using a software named NAMD. and the codes look something like this-

```
!/content/NAMD_2.14_Linux-x86_64-multicore-CUDA/namd2 +auto-provision /content/drive/MyDrive/somewhere/production.inp > /content/drive/MyDrive/somewhere/prd_logs.log
```

basically, the NAMD2 software takes input from the `production.inp` and generates the log file as `prd_logs.log` along with other output files.

there are 2 key problems-

1. the runtime gets disconnected when I close the browser and/or internet connection is lost.
2. the log file sometimes gets deleted totally after the run is discontinued, and I have no way of knowing how much work was done before the code was terminated.

how can I fix these two problems? There was a comment on a related thread ([hyperlinked here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66340015/22361376)) that said,

> for me, I choose ,chroot into VM by ssh Ngrok and run command shell (loop) in background
> `while true;do sleep 300; done &` I'm using &` for to run this command in the background so I can exit from website of colab and leave the VM working, for 12h.

But how do a run a code in background inside colab? I have limited coding skills so someone please help me.